# how to generate random 16-char hex string, then divide by 4 using dashes (-) in python?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to use python to first generate a random 16-character hex string, like so

`ABCDEF1234567890`

and then separate each 4 characters by dash, like this

`ABCD-EF12-3456-7890`

preferably in one line in python.

How can I do this exactly?

Comment: Why don't you want to create four 4-character hex strings first, and then join them with dashes?

Comment: Fast way of generating a 4- character hex string would be `'%04X' % randint(0, 0xFFFF)`

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```py
from random import choice

hexrand  ='-'.join([''.join([choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for _ in range(4)]) for _ in range(4)])

print(hexrand)

""""
Sample Output
DC40-D346-B7E0-2440
0945-9EBB-95D1-8892

""""
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this out.

```
import random

def generate():    
    return ''.join(random.choices('123456789ABCDEF', k = 4))

temp = []
for _ in range(4):
    temp.append(generate())

print('-'.join(temp))
```

```
F88A-D42B-E2EC-4677
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import random
def generate_string():
    return ''.join(random.choices('0123456789ABCDEF',k=4))
string1='-'.join([generate_string() for x in range(4)])
print(string1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an intuitive and simple solution.

```py
from random import choice
width = 4  # how many characters per block
blocks = 4  # how many width length blocks to have
all_hex_chars = [hex(i)[-1].upper() for i in range(1, 16)]
output = [[choice(all_hex_chars) for _ in range(width)] for _ in range(blocks)]
formatted_output = '-'.join([''.join(i) for i in output])
print(formatted_output)
```

And a one-liner:

```
output = '-'.join(''.join([[choice(all_hex_chars) for _ in range(4)] for i in range(4)]))
```

Please ignore my overcomplicated hex generator on line 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
'-'.join('%04X' % random.randint(0, 0xFFFF) for _ in range(4))
```

Generates four four-digit hex numbers and joins them up.

Remember to use `secrets` instead of `random` if this is meant to be a code.